# Where did Metternich say the Balkans began?

Tags: quotes, austria, the-balkans

Statesman and politician of Austrian Empire, [Klemens von Metternich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemens_von_Metternich) made somewhere his famous remark that "Balkan already begins on some road south from Vienna". Does anybody knows where was that road, according to Metternich?

Answer (score 12):

[Prince Metternich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemens_von_Metternich) is reputed to have said, ***"The Balkans begin at the Rennweg"***. The Rennweg [is a street](https://goo.gl/maps/uK1PHCogPQC2) that led southwest out of the [Austrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_Empire) capital, [Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna). It runs through modern Vienna's third district, [Landstraße](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landstra%C3%9Fe).

Another variant of the supposed quote is, *"Asia begins at the Landstrasse"*.

Comment: "_Asien beginnt an der Landstraße_"

Answer (score 9):

The road in question, the Rennweg, begins at the [Landstrasse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landstra%C3%9Fe) in the south center of modern Vienna, at the southern edge of what was then Vienna.

When Metternich referred to the "Balkans," he was referring to the non-German speaking part of Austria, variously referred to as the "east" of even as "Asia."
This was because it represented the "high water mark" of Ottoman (Turkish) expansion in 1683. After Austria began the "rollback" of Turkish power, to the south and east (in modern Hungary and the former Yugoslavia), it captured formerly Ottoman, ("Asian") lands that were treated in a "stepchild" fashion.

Metternich's great diplomatic achievement was to preserve Austria's position in the 1815 ["Concert of Europe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert_of_Europe) of Britain, Russia, Prussia, and Austria. A companion to this was the  formation of the [German Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Confederation), initially under Austrian leadership. Prince Metternich's preference was for Austria to maintain this role, even if she had to divest some non-German parts of the empire (Hungary and territories in the former Yugoslavia) to preserve her "bona fides," while retaining Austria, the modern Czech Republic, Slovakia, and occupied Poland (all of which figured in the German balance of power). Other Austrian leaders disagreed, and thereby let Prussia become the de facto leader of the German Confederation.

Comment: Austria with ... Britain, Russia, Prussia, and Austria??? And France, probably?

Comment: divest OF what?

Comment: @ Gangnus: Changed to OF Britain, Russia, Prussia, and Austria. France was added later. As for "divestment," Hungary could have been "let go," and DID want to be "let go" around 1848. Pieces of the former Yugoslavia also didn't fit. Basically, they were not part of the "Germanic" world (Poland and the Czech Republic were).  Earlier on, it was a "hypothetical" but as time passed, the question was actually put to Austria.

Comment: Dear Tom, I only wanted to point at some places that could cause misunderstanding. Austria could not stay WITH Austria. You have corrected the preposition, I understand now this sentence, thank you. I still do not understand the use of the word divest. According to the dicts, it has the same grammar use as deprive OF .... "Of ..."  is necessary.  As a result, I still do not understand the corresponding sentence, sorry.

Comment: According to your explanation in the comment, Metternich should be the best friend of Russia? For Russian in XIX Cent tried to move in the direction of Balkans and had no interests in Germany. But as far as I remember, he was a direct enemy of Russia.

Comment: @Gangnus: Metternich was driven mainly by balance of power considerations, sometimes against, sometimes for, Russia, depending on who was more threatening. But his strategy was to ally with "German" states (with the possible exception of Prussia). The Ottoman Empire also figured in this balance of power. So letting go of the former "Ottoman" territories as a buffer zone wouldn't have been the worst idea in the world.

Comment: Metternich wanted to have a balance? I thought that was an English aim. Only the distant standalone player wants others to be in balance, and Austria as a direct participant in everything, needed to prevail. But your main thought, that the exact aims changed, I do like. Yes, speaking of his changing targets, we should name dates. And that is what your post absolutely lack, what makes it less useful.